# mysql : turn fraction strings into number

Tags: mysql

I have strings like... "3/4" and "5/9" and some like... "1/2 km" and "3/4 degree" stored in mysql columns.

I would like to convert them into numbers. 
In first case, 3/4 ==> .75.
In more complicated second case, strip off units like "km" and "degree" so 
"1/2 km" ==> 0.5.

Comment: I'd recommend doing this in the application and not the database. It doesn't really sound like something a database was really designed to do.

Comment: It also doesn't really sound like a particularly sensible data storage format.

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't something you should do in a query, but rather calculate it when it is stored and save the calculated value in the table next to its text value.

But if you want to, you can use some string functions to slice up the value and the do the math yourself:

```
select
  x.Multiplier / x.Divider as Result
from
    (select
      cast( substr( t.String, 
                    1, 
                    locate('/', t.String) - 1) 
            as decimal) 
        as Multiplier,
      cast( substr( t.String, 
                    locate('/', t.String) + 1, 
                    locate( ' ', 
                            concat(t.String, ' '))) 
            as decimal) 
        as Divider
    from
      YourTable t) x
```

Note however, that this may cause trouble if the data is 'invalid'. If it says '0/0 km', it may fail, if it contains 'no data here' it may fail as well.

Comment: I agree with this recommended approach. I've posted a PHP solution below (finger in the air)

Comment: I've seen it. It was there before mine. :) Using PHP is fine, but no reference was made of PHP, so I don't know if OP uses it. Also, you may need the value in the query to do, for example, sorting by distance and only get records of less than 10km or so. You would have to move that to PHP as well, while a database is much better at sorting and filtering, and you'll have to query more data, increasing database load, php server load and network traffic (if they are different servers).

Comment: thanks.  i'm not using PHP and dealing with legacy database that already has yucky formatting hence the awkward requirements.   i think i'll try above approach because i can make the code tolerate the invalid cases.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't quite work for me so came up with this which does.  The query works for '10', '3/4' and '10 3/4'.  Obviously you should replace the constructed rows at the bottom with your string or a selected value from a table:

```
SELECT 
    IF (
        LOCATE(' ',fraction) > 0 OR LOCATE('/',fraction) = 0,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fraction,'/','1'),' ','1')
        ,0
    ) AS `integer`,
    IF (
        LOCATE('/',fraction) > 0,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fraction,'/','1'),' ','-1'),
        0
    ) AS numerator,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(fraction,'/','-1') AS denominator,
    (SELECT `integer`) + ((SELECT numerator) / (SELECT denominator)) AS `decimal`
FROM (
    SELECT '10 3/4' AS fraction
    UNION SELECT '10'
    UNION SELECT '3/4'
) t;
```

Answer (score -1):

With PHP you could do:

```
// assuming $vals has the values from the database
$converted = array();
foreach ($vals as $key => $val) {
  preg_match("/^(\\d+)\\/(\\d+)/", $val, $matches)
  if (count($matches) > 2) {
    $numerator = (int) $matches[1];
    $denominator = (int) $matches[2];
    $converted[$key] = (float) $numerator / $denominator;
  }
}
```