# How to convert a string fraction "1 1/2" to float in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, casting, floating-point

I've got a varchar column with values that are either a simple number (eg "30"), or a number and a half (eg "30 1/2").

Is there a way for me to convert these into floats in a new column using only SQL?  I'd prefer not to code this up elsewhere if I can avoid it.

Comment: so you just want to convert varchar to float ??

Comment: I suspect that you want to convert them to decimals

Comment: Do you have only "1/2" or other fractions as well?

Comment: You could try with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032997/mysql-turn-fraction-strings-into-number

Comment: @Leandro The question is unambiguous on this point.

Comment: @AvinashBabu Yes I want to convert the fractions to decimals.

Comment: So the @Strawberry answer is not useful because only works for a one particular case. I suggest to OP edit the question to be more specific and get an specific answer.

Comment: @Leandro It only works in one particular case... Which happens to be the only case with which the problem is concerned. Feel free to provide a more general solution

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE('30 1/2',' 1/2','.5')+0;
+---------------------------------+
| REPLACE('30 1/2',' 1/2','.5')+0 |
+---------------------------------+
|                            30.5 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please update your answer with the need of the OP (see comments below question).

Comment: Ok. I assume that adding zero to a string in MySQL results in an Int/Float?  Is that what's going on there?  Any particular gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: Yes. Probably not really necessary in this instance, and no gotchas