# How can I dynamically convert integer 16ths of inch to fractional inch using mysql code?

Tags: mysql

I have stored values for size as integers that represent 16ths of an inch.

Example:

```
1 = 1/16"
4 = 1/4" 
8 = 1/2"
16 = 1"
24 = 1 1/2"
32 = 2"
```

I currently use a two column table to do a lookup of the integer value and return already calculated fraction of inch. I would prefer to make this more dynamic and have **mysql select code** or a **mysql function** do the conversion on the fly and not need to store statically converted values for every possible integer value.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901215/56082) appears to be close to the reverse of what I would need also it deals with decimals vs integers so it is not the exact reverse.

The goal is integer value as input with string output being the division but also the correct representation of fractional inch (i.e. 12 should be 3/4", not 12/16" and 28 should 1 3/4", not 28/16")

The converted value isn't going to be used in any `where` clauses or indexed as it not a searchable value. It is for output of results only.

Expert ideas on how to tackle this math and conversion or is there an existing solution somewhere?

**Update** The solution I implemented uses the selected answer below:

```
CONCAT(
  IF(sixteenths > 15,       /* The integer part, if any */
   FLOOR(sixteenths/16),
   ''
  ),
  IF(sixteenths % 16 = 0,   /* The fractional part, if any */
   '',
  CONCAT(
    IF(sixteenths > 15, ' ', ''),  /* A space between 1 and 1/2" */
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(              /* Use correct fractions from set */
     '1/16,1/8,3/16,1/4,5/16,3/8,7/16,1/2,9/16,5/8,11/16,3/4,13/16,7/8,15/16',
     ',', 
     sixteenths % 16
     ),
   ',', -1
  ))
  ),
  '"'            /* Inches symbol */
);
```

I've now used this code in a function that can be called when querying data from many tables that all have large data sets in the database that all need to have this conversion as output when doing large results set (not used as search criteria).

The resulting benefits are a dynamic, reusable, no limits to pre-created data sets (i.e. it can be used for an integer of any value not previously contemplated) and no tables required solution that is executed at the database level instead of application level so it is very fast when dealing with large data results sets!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Ultimately, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Dynamic conversion of the column's stored integer value to the correct fractional inch as a string so I can eliminate the need for a second table that has all of the conversions already applied statically.

Comment: Store the integer values. It's far simpler,and allows actual index operations on it (if you ever need that).  Just add a new column to your existing table, and when you insert a row, insert both the human-readable value (`1 3/16`), and the machine-readable (`1.1875`).

Comment: The integer values are already stored, that's not going to be changed. The conversion is for output only not used for searching or indexing. The same goal applies to your 'adding a new column' approach as someone or some code has to do the conversion for 100s of thousands of records that can have integer values ranging from 1..200

Comment: If `SELECT SIXTEENTHS/16 AS INCHES FROM xxx` Isn't the answer I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to reimplement your lookup table. Unfortunately, since this function returns items from the one specified *onwards*, to get only *one* element you need to invoke it in a [complicated way](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/01/23/mysql-select-the-n-th-element-from-a-delimiter-separated-value-set/):

> First one call SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the portion of the string that contain the first n values, and then a second call to get the last value from the subset!
>
> In this example we extract the 4th value from a string containing
>   animals:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @values = 'cat#dog#horse#parrot#gecko';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@values,'#',4),'#',-1);
> +--------------------------------------------------------+
> | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@values,'#',4),'#',-1) |
> +--------------------------------------------------------+
> | parrot                                                 |
> +--------------------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> In general, to select the N-th value from a string VALUES that
>   contains values separated by delimiter DELIM, you have to use:
>
> ```
> SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( VALUES, DELIM, N ), DELIM, -1 )
> ```

This is not significantly more or less efficient than a mathematical formula, because, for instance, they both will prevent any optimization on the *sixteenths* column if used in a `WHERE`. That is, if you do a search for parts of '1 3/4"' caliber, the server will in both cases *perform a full table scan*. Such searches would best be handled back-translating the queried value into sixteenths before plugging it into the query.

Or you can pour it into a literal lookup *table* (I see you already considered this):

```
CREATE TABLE trans16(six integer, inch varchar(16));

SELECT (SELECT inch FROM trans16 WHERE six = sixteenths) AS textual, ...
```

The first option would work best for last-step selects, while the second would be more efficient with larger, complex queries (the "back-translation" would be handled by MySQL).

Alternately, you can first extract the "integer" part using an `IF()`:

```
IF(sixteenths >= 16, FLOOR(sixteenths/16), '')
```

This will be nothing for values below one inch, or it will be the integer inches. Then, the value

```
`sixteenths % 16`
```

will either be zero or a number from 1 to 15, so

```
IF(sixteenths % 16 = 0, 
   '',
   CONCAT(' ', {FORMULA_ABOVE_USING_SUBSTRING_INDEX}  )
)
```

will yield either an empty string or the appropriate fractional part. You can save the CONCAT by placing the space, fifteen times, in all strings in the set string.

The final formula looks like:

```
CONCAT(
    IF(sixteenths > 15,       /* The integer part, if any */
       FLOOR(sixteenths/16),
       ''
    ),
    IF(sixteenths % 16 = 0,   /* The fractional part, if any */
       '',
       CONCAT(
         IF(sixteenths > 15, ' ', ''),  /* A space between 1 and 1/2" */
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               '1/16,1/8,3/16,1/4,5/16,3/8,7/16,1/2,9/16,5/8,11/16,3/4,13/16,7/8,15/16',
               ',',
               sixteenths%16
             ),
             ',', -1
         )
       )
    ),
    '"'
);
```

**You will not be able to get `3/2"` this way** - it will be represented as `1 1/2"`.

The same logic can be used for an user-defined function. Get the integer part, then a lookup table for the sixteenths.

You might use this approach for the lookup table also, but now it probably isn't worth the trouble.

Finally, you can do without the lookup table:

```
                  %4   %2
1       1/16      1    0
2       1/8       2    1
3       3/16      3    0
4       1/4       0    1
5       5/16      1
6       3/8       2
7       7/16      3
8       1/2       0
9       9/16
10      5/8
11      11/16
12      3/4
13      13/16
14      7/8
15      15/16
```

So you can have /2's, /4's, /8's, and /16'. When do you have them? When the modulo 8 is 0 you have halves; when modulo 4 is 0 you have fourths; when modulo 2 is 0 you have eighths; otherwise it's sixteenths.

The lookup table becomes

```
IF((s%16)%8,
    IF((s%16)%4,
        IF((s%16)%2,
            CONCAT(s%16, '/16"')
        ,CONCAT(FLOOR((s%16)/2), '/8"'))
    ,CONCAT(FLOOR((s%16)/4), '/4"'))
,CONCAT(FLOOR((s%16)/8), '/2"'))
```

and the final formula without indexes, using a table to test:

```
SELECT sixteenths, CONCAT(        
    IF(sixteenths > 15,
        FLOOR(sixteenths/16),
        ''
     ),
     IF(sixteenths % 16 = 0,
        '',
        CONCAT(
          IF(sixteenths > 15, ' ', ''),
            IF((sixteenths%16)%8,
              IF((sixteenths%16)%4,
                 IF((sixteenths%16)%2,
                    CONCAT(FLOOR(sixteenths%16), '/16')
                      ,CONCAT(FLOOR((sixteenths%16)/2), '/8'))
                  ,CONCAT(FLOOR((sixteenths%16)/4), '/4'))
              ,CONCAT(FLOOR((sixteenths%16)/8), '/2'))
        )
     ),
     '"'
 ) AS `text` FROM ttt;
```

yields:

```
+------------+----------+
| sixteenths | text     |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | 1/16"    |
|          2 | 1/8"     |
|          3 | 3/16"    |
|          4 | 1/4"     |
|          5 | 5/16"    |
|          6 | 3/8"     |
|          7 | 7/16"    |
|          8 | 1/2"     |
|          9 | 9/16"    |
|         10 | 5/8"     |
|         11 | 11/16"   |
|         12 | 3/4"     |
|         13 | 13/16"   |
|         14 | 7/8"     |
|         15 | 15/16"   |
|         16 | 1"       |
|         17 | 1 1/16"  |
|         18 | 1 1/8"   |
|         19 | 1 3/16"  |
|         20 | 1 1/4"   |
|         21 | 1 5/16"  |
|         22 | 1 3/8"   |
|         23 | 1 7/16"  |
|         24 | 1 1/2"   |
|         25 | 1 9/16"  |
|         26 | 1 5/8"   |
|         27 | 1 11/16" |
|         28 | 1 3/4"   |
|         29 | 1 13/16" |
|         30 | 1 7/8"   |
|         31 | 1 15/16" |
|         32 | 2"       |
```

Comment: This still requires statically defining all possible conversions ahead of time. I am looking for a dynamic conversion. Imagine there are 200 possible values.

Comment: I see now. Added to the answer.

Comment: Interesting, this is sort of a half step so instead of a lookup table of ~200 values, its a lookup table of only 16. Would be great to have a fully dynamic solution with no lookup table but will noodle on this more and come back to it.

Comment: I've added a proposal for a fully dynamic construct. You should consider only translating it when outputting the data, however; perhaps even in the front-end.

Comment: Thanks for the fully dynamic proposal, going to explore it now and compare that and your original find_in_set while adding the whole value extraction. I was curious about using find_in_set with the smaller set of only the fractions where the integer % 16 is 1 to 15. However, find_in_set doesn't work to locate a positional match in the set, it just seeks to find the match in the set which would suggest `sixteenths` is already converted to a fraction vs being an integer, correct? Is there a way to define a set like that and find it by the integer % 16 value as its position without using a table?

Comment: **SORRY**. Whatever was I thinking? I've given you the *wrong function*! You want `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, not `FIND_IN_SET`! Since you're not interested in that part anyway, I'm removing it from my answer and hope nobody ever learns about this.

Comment: Tests using SUBSTRING_INDEX based example in this answer appear to be doing the trick! I'll follow up more a little later or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a code and you want a string representation of it.  One method is a user-defined function.  I think a simpler method is simply a look-up table:

```
create table SixteenthsToString (
    num int primary key;
    representation varchar(255)
);

insert into SixteenthsToString
    values (0, '0"'),
           (1, '1/16"'),
           (2, '1/8"'),
           . . .
```

Unless you have a ridiculously large range, it is probably faster to create and populate such a table than to attempt other means.  You would then use this as:

```
select t.*, t16.representation
from t left join
     SixteenthsToString t16
     on t.code = t16.num;
```

Comment: Ya, this is what I have now that I am trying to replace with a user-defined function.